# Developing a local npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am developing a npm package. Lets call it `my-library`. I publish this package to a private npm repository which is pulled by many of my projects. How can I quickly develop the code in `my-library` without having to publish a new version of `my-library` every time I make a small change?

Take the following workflow for example:

1. I make a change to `my-library`. The change is still in development so I don't want to publish it to all my consumers yet, but I do want to test it locally.
2. I run `npm pack` to create a local `.tgz` file.
3. In one of my dependent projects, say `my-consumer` I update the `package.json` to reference this local `.tgz` file. `"my-library": "file:../some/path/my-package.tgz"`
4. I run `npm install` in `my-consumer` and my local package is not installed and I can test my app.

Now, there isn't anything apparently wrong with the aforementioned steps, but say I am very quickly iterating on `my-library` and I want to make and test changes very quickly. Is there any way I can make the above process go faster? Running pack and install for every little change takes time and is much slower than if this were hot-reloading. Can I configure my package.json in `my-consumer` to use a cached version of `my-library` that is not in the node_modules folder and skip some of the above steps? I also don't want this to introduce any dependency issues.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link?

Comment: You might consider using a monorepo setup if these projects are closely related.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When using npm-link, if I make changes to my library, will those changes be immediately reflected in my consumer? Like, suppose that was already running in a hot-reload mode (like `npm run serve` or something). Or are there other steps I would need to take as well? Do I need to rebuild my library or reinstall in my consumer? Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to say, it depends what's running, whether it watches the dependencies for changes, whether it follows symlinks, ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using npm/yarm link for that. it allows you to symlink your library to your project, and therefore have the most updated code without any publish and install.

Basically the syntax is:

```bash
cd /path/to/lib
yarn link
cd /path/to/project
yarn link myLibName
```

Take a look at the [`yarn link` docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link).